# How to call a function in controller from different directives and controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a modal which is defined inside a modalController.
This modal can be called from other directives.
What is the right way to achieve this?

As I see, sharedService is one approach.
In brief,

```
var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.open = function () {
      console.log("Open popup");
  });
});

// In another or any other directive
app.directive('myDirective', [
function($scope, $document,windowService) {

    return {
        controller : function($scope,windowService,docsService){                
            //Its own controller.   
        },
        link : function(scope,element,attars){
            //Call popup controller on some event(say click) here.
            // ModalCtrl.open()
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a template for the directive?

Comment: currently not, but may be future directives might have. How that effects the outcome?

Comment: what's exactly you want to do in the modal? Is it a modal in ui-bootstrap? more detail please.

Comment: yes, modal is direct copy from ui-bootstrap, I am experimenting with it and want modal to be invoked from various events in other directives.

Comment: I was reading http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive yesterday. down the bottom there is one section "Creating Directives that Communicate". maybe you can experiment and let us know

Answer (score 0):

pass `open()` to mydirective's scope

```
<my-directive event="open()"></my-directive>
```

use `&` to bind behavior to `scope.event`

and then bind click event to element

```
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
    event: '&'
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.on('click', scope.event);
},
```